# Expression Web 3.0 SuperPreview on a .Net MVC 1.0 Web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-expression-web, superpreview

We are trying to use Web Expression 3.0 feature SuperPreview to make our site consistent across multiple browsers.

Our's is a MVC 1.0 application. Has anyone tried to use SuperPreview on that ?

Your advise will be very helpful.

Comment: This question is nonsensical. Do you have a problem with something?

Answer (score 0):

SuperPreview just loads pages through different rendering engines...so it shouldn't matter what kind of web application you are testing (WebForms, .NET MVC, etc.).

...on that note, I have tested .NET MVC apps and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you guide me on how were you able to click on hyperlinks to move from One controller to another ? 

I am speaking more in terms of Live/Hosted Website

Comment: ok.. Just to add with isses: Our is more of a work flow application. We need to enter data on first page and then click next button to get to another page. And so we want to test our site through SuprePreview.